# The non-abstract class 'InternalSelectableMathState' is missing implementations for these members

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3/lib/src/widgets/selectable.dart:407:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'InternalSelectableMathState' is missing implementations for these members:

- TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection
- TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection
- TextSelectionDelegate.pasteText
- TextSelectionDelegate.selectAll
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class InternalSelectableMathState extends State
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:985:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection' is defined here.
void copySelection(SelectionChangedCause cause);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:965:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection' is defined here.
void cutSelection(SelectionChangedCause cause);
^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:973:16: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.pasteText' is defined here.
Future pasteText(SelectionChangedCause cause);
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:979:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.selectAll' is defined here.
void selectAll(SelectionChangedCause cause);
^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_datetime_picker-1.5.1/lib/flutter_datetime_picker.dart:311:32: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'Color' which excludes null.

- 'Color' is from 'dart:ui'.
  color: theme.backgroundColor ?? Colors.white,
  ^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_neumorphic-3.1.0/lib/src/widget/button.dart:200:14: Error: 'AnimatedScale' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart' and 'package:flutter_neumorphic/src/widget/animation/animated_scale.dart'.
  child: AnimatedScale(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_neumorphic-3.1.0/lib/src/widget/switch.dart:167:20: Error: 'AnimatedScale' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/widgets/implicit_animations.dart' and 'package:flutter_neumorphic/src/widget/animation/animated_scale.dart'.
  child: AnimatedScale(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can you include your  code-snippet?

Comment: have you find any solution..?

Answer (score 20):

You need to upgrade your dependencies to fix this issue, so run:

flutter pub upgrade

Answer (score 6):

I faced this error once I upgraded to Flutter 2.8.1.

Solution:
just add `flutter_math_fork: ^0.5.0` to your dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` to force Flutter to use the newer version of the package.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70335197/11217945)

Comment: I am facing the issue of plugin compatibility for flutter_math_fork: ^0.5.0, if I am using flutter_math_fork: ^0.3.3+1 this doesn't make any conflicts while pub gets but the error remains the same. Is there any other solution for this!!??