# Error while installing Webrtc based app on Android

Tags: flutter, flutter-webrtc

Geeting below error while installing WebRTC based app on Android but its working fine on Browser.

Getting below error:

Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.8.4/lib/src/native/rtc_data_channel_impl.dart:16:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'RTCDataChannelNative' is missing implementations for these members:

- RTCDataChannel.bufferedAmount
- RTCDataChannel.id
  Try to either
- provide an implementation,
- inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
- mark the class as abstract, or
- provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class RTCDataChannelNative extends RTCDataChannel {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webrtc_interface-1.0.3/lib/src/rtc_data_channel.dart:79:12: Context: 'RTCDataChannel.bufferedAmount' is defined here.
int? get bufferedAmount;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webrtc_interface-1.0.3/lib/src/rtc_data_channel.dart:74:12: Context: 'RTCDataChannel.id' is defined here.
int? get id;
^^

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your dependencies to fix this issue, so run:

flutter pub upgrade

same:
[The non-abstract class 'InternalSelectableMathState' is missing implementations for these members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70473202/the-non-abstract-class-internalselectablemathstate-is-missing-implementations)