# Error: The non-abstract class 'InternalSelectableMathState' is missing implementations for these members - Flutter 2.8.1

Tags: flutter

Here I am upgrading my Flutter 2.5 to 2.8. When I tried to run my previous existing project, I found this error. But in 2.5 it works everything perfectly.

I am trying this from StackOverflow: [The same issue, But I am couldn't solve by this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70334900/error-the-non-abstract-class-internalselectablemathstate/70335197#70335197)

I found this error --

```
[satota_app] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in satota_app...                      
Because google_maps_place_picker >=2.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on provider ^5.0.0 and no versions of google_maps_place_picker match >=2.0.0-nullsafety <2.0.0-nullsafety.0, google_maps_place_picker >=2.0.0-nullsafety requires provider ^5.0.0.
So, because satota_app depends on both provider ^6.0.2 and google_maps_place_picker ^2.0.0-nullsafety, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because satota_app depends on both provider ^6.0.2 and google_maps_place_picker ^2.0.0-nullsafety, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

How can I solve this problem?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1820 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
/C:/Users/ramja/Documents/DartConfig/flutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.3.3+1/lib/src/widgets/selectable.dart:407:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'InternalSelectableMathState' is missing implementations for these members:
 - TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection
 - TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection
 - TextSelectionDelegate.pasteText
 - TextSelectionDelegate.selectAll
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class InternalSelectableMathState extends State<InternalSelectableMath>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/ramja/Documents/DartConfig/flutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:985:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.copySelection' is defined here.
  void copySelection(SelectionChangedCause cause);

       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/ramja/Documents/DartConfig/flutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:965:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.cutSelection' is defined here.
  void cutSelection(SelectionChangedCause cause);
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^

/C:/Users/ramja/Documents/DartConfig/flutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:973:16: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.pasteText' is defined here.
  Future<void> pasteText(SelectionChangedCause cause);
               ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/ramja/Documents/DartConfig/flutterSDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:979:8: Context: 'TextSelectionDelegate.selectAll' is defined here.
  void selectAll(SelectionChangedCause cause);

       ^^^^^^^^^
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\ramja\Documents\DartConfig\flutterSDK\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\ramja\Documents\DartConfig\flutterSDK\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

**My Pubspec.yml is :**

```
name: satota_app
description: This is the flutter mobile application for satota     
publish_to: 'none'  
version: 2.0.0+10

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  http:  
  provider: ^5.0.0
  flutter_math_fork: #if I use any version of this package output is status code -1
  json_annotation:  
  logging:  
  connectivity: 
  shimmer:  
  bordered_text:  
  flutter_html:
  flutter_svg:  
  url_launcher: 
  toast:
  shared_preferences:
  flutter_icons:
  dotted_line:
  timeline_list:
  progress_dialog:
  after_init:
  webview_flutter:
  clipboard: 
  google_fonts:
  flutter_rating_bar:
  expandable:
  dropdown_search:
  flutter_countdown_timer:
  splashscreen:
  package_info:
  intl_phone_number_input: 
  flutter_chat_bubble:
 
  cupertino_icons: 
  carousel_slider: 
  cached_network_image: 
  timeline_tile: 
  shared_value: 
  rename: 
  permission_handler: 
  image_picker: 
  flutter_facebook_auth:
  google_sign_in:
  google_maps_place_picker: ^2.0.0-nullsafety 
  firebase_messaging: 
  one_context:
  social_share:
  flutter_typeahead:
  photo_view: 
  intl: 
  
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner:
  json_serializable:
  flutter_launcher_icons:
  google_maps_flutter: 


flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/app_logo.png"
 
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true
  assets:
    - assets/
    - dummy_assets/
```

thanks.......

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70334900/error-the-non-abstract-class-internalselectablemathstate

Comment: I am solve this, Flutter 2.8 to 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Try running: $ dart fix --apply